# Gvfs permissions denied in syslog

Tags: gvfs

My syslog is generating this the following two lines every second.

O

```
ct 19 06:27:09 wally org.gnome.panel.applet.MultiLoadAppletFactory[1911]: glibtop: statvfs '/root/.gvfs' failed: Permission denied
Oct 19 06:27:09 wally org.gnome.panel.applet.MultiLoadAppletFactory[1911]: glibtop: statvfs '/run/user/1001/gvfs' failed: Permission denied
```

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10.   Any way to tell what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same.  Appears to be tracked at https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-applets/issues/171 - and possibly also https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1355867.

(At this point, this is recognized to be an answer, but not exactly a solution.  I'll attempt to update this answer if I can find a resolution.)